# how to replace the word in double quotes in unix

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am looking for the following requirement.

Input file will have the string

```
CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_EMP" ON "SCOTT"."EMP" ("EMP_ID")
```

I would like to see output as following

```
CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_EMP" ON "SCOTT"."T_EMP" ("EMP_ID")
```

So, I have written the statement like following

```
$file_name.sql=sed -e "s/"ON SCOTT"."/"ON SCOTT"."T_/ig" $file_name.sql
```

Unfortunately, in my output file I miss scott and output file contains the following

```
CREATE INDEX IX_EMP ON T_EMP
```

Could you please help me in getting the required output value?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 's/ON "SCOTT"."EMP/ON "SCOTT"."T_EMP/g'
```

The trick here is that the single quotes escape the double quotes (effectively turning them into normal characters) so you can use them in the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The following sed command should do the conversion.

```
sed -e 's/ON "SCOTT"."/ON "SCOTT"."T_/'
```

This assumes that you want to replace all instance of ON "SCOTT"." with ON "SCOTT"."T_

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i ".bak" -e 's/"EMP"/"T_EMP"/' ${file_name.sql}
```

tehre is only 1 "EMP" to change (in your sample)